# Cocoa Scripting: Return a floating point (double) value for "any" type

Tags: applescript, cocoa-scripting

When specifying the `any` type for a command result in the Sdef, it seems that one cannot simply return the NS types such as `NSNumber`. Instead, one needs to return an `NSAppleEventDescriptor`.

However, `NSAppleEventDescriptor` is rather limited in the values it can handle. There appears to be no support for floating point numbers such as C's `double` type.

How do I return double values for the `any` type, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.11 has a direct way, a `doubleValue` property, for system versions prior to 10.11 you can coerce the descriptor with the method `coerceToDescriptorType` to one of these types

```
typeIEEE32BitFloatingPoint = 'sing',
typeIEEE64BitFloatingPoint = 'doub',
type128BitFloatingPoint = 'ldvl',
```

For example code see [AppleScriptToolKit](https://github.com/yangyubo/AppleScriptToolkit/blob/master/NSAppleEventDescriptor%2BNumber.m)

Comment: That helped. I was able to create the value with `[[NSAppleEventDescriptor alloc] initWithDescriptorType:'doub' bytes:&doubleVar length: sizeof(double)]`

Comment: `NSAppleEventDescriptor` is actually not as *limited* as it seems to be ;-) All supported types are listed in the [Apple Event Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Apple_Event_Manager)

Comment: Yeah, reading and understanding the AE Mgr docs - that's another week's task, though :)